# BigQuery : An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed

Tags: google-bigquery

Simple select queries with timestamp are failing :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [bi.table] WHERE  timestamp > DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -15, 'MINUTE') and column1 is null
```

Query Failed:

```
Error: An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed. Job ID: exampleJob:job_lndEirUwwM_khdBrV8eMDmBDFiE
```

Is there anything wrong with the bigquery system?

https://status.cloud.google.com/ does not say anything is wrong.

Comment: Can you show the query?

Comment: @Leptonator Edited question

Comment: Looks like it's working now :)

Comment: Can you post your final resolution?  This way, it may be able to help other people in the future?

Comment: @EranChetzroni did you change anything or it just works for you now?

Comment: @Bulat it was indeed an internal error with the ingestion system. see Dan Delorey answer below, if you are still expriencing issues, I suggest opening a ticket with Google Cloud Support. good luck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Bigquery: In internal error occurred and the request could not be completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069185/google-bigquery-in-internal-error-occurred-and-the-request-could-not-be-complet)

Comment: There are several open issues in the tracker for this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142457683

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error was actually unrelated to the timestamps. You hit an error in our streaming ingestion service. It was overloaded at the time you ran your query and it could not serve the data that had been ingested for your table. We are investigating and will fix the underlying issue. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Experiencing this now on the `2019-10-09`. Is there anything we can consider doing to prevent this from happening?

Comment: And again at 2020-02-13 ... any chance to get more info?

Comment: @Hirnhamster/@Bulat ... Could you please tell me how you have resolved this issue.

Comment: And again at 2021-02-14

Comment: And again in `2021-09-13`

Comment: And again in 2021-09-22

Comment: and hey! again in 2021-11-04

Answer (score -5):

Recommendation is to never use a wildcard with COUNT..  Especially large tables.  If we re-write your query a bit, we get:

```
SELECT COUNT(user) count_user
FROM [bi.table]
WHERE  timestamp > DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -15, 'MINUTE')
and column1 is null
```

depending on the API, you can also use:

```
and isnull(column1)
```

you can also use:

```
and isnull(column1)
```

you can also use:

```
and isempty(column1)
```

you can also use:

```
and column1=''
```

This is using the KB article from Microsoft talking about the difference between isnull(column1) or colum1 is null..

Also, with SQL server..  You can use Locking Hints..

```
FROM [bi.table] (NOLOCK)
```

but, I am not familiar with the Google API...  So, these are just suggestions.

Comment: I don't thin this is the reason for the error, nonetheless, I will revise our query. Thanks a lot! @Leptonator

Comment: Please keep in mind: `SELECT COUNT(*)..` has to do a huge table scan.  If you choose a column that is always populated, it is much more efficient use of resources.  Locking hints can also be helpful.  Another way you could do this would be to create a view in to the not null 'column1' recordset and then base your count on the last 15 minutes from there.

Comment: COUNT(*) does not scan the entire table. It is discouraged because it can return unexpected results when repeated fields are involved. That is why you should consider counting a specific field whenever you can. But, COUNT(*) does not adversely affect the number of fields scanned. In fact, as explained on the pricing page (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing), the query "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table" processes zero bytes.

Comment: This answer is not terribly related to the question, and it has also turned out to be incorrect with regards to BigQuery (as explained by @DanDelorey)