# Google Bigquery: In internal error occurred and the request could not be completed

Tags: google-bigquery

I am having difficulty getting a BigQuery job to execute from the Web Interface.  If I try to run the job I get the error message

```
Error: An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.
Job ID: rhi-localytics-db:job_V-6F5YOk0k9ENTgDfGX84Ghnxz8
```

Does anyone have any idea what problem this error message means?  The query I'm using is not terribly complicated.

Thanks,
Brad

Comment: you should present your query so more chances to get help

Comment: In other cases the Google folks have indicated it's a problem with their back end and they have wanted the Job ID to look into it. That leads me to believe it's not the query itself, so I was hoping that someone from Google would be able to help. Plus in order to post the query I feel like I'd have to obfuscate it a fair amount, and I'd prefer not to spend the time doing that unless it's absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the internal error details and your query appears to have hit a transient internal error.  The error should have nothing to do with your specific query.  We'll investigate internally to reduce the occurrence of errors like this.

Does your query reliably fail with this error if you rerun it, or did you only receive this error on the one query job?

Comment: It failed several times, I think I tried it 3 times?

Okay, thanks, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Hmm, that's more failures than I'd expect.  If the problem persists, please report a new issue with the relevant job IDs on our [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the report. We are now tracking the issue internally.