# Google BigQuery Internal Error

Tags: google-bigquery

All of the sudden this morning I've been unable to run any BigQuery queries.

I try running just "select 1" and get this response:

Query Failed
Error: An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.
Job ID: remilon-study:bquijob_1c8abe36_156b86c9942

This is happening to all my queries.  Google's cloud status page shows everything is fine.  Thanks.

Comment: This just ended up magically fixing itself a few minutes ago.  I'm still a little curious what caused this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Bigquery: In internal error occurred and the request could not be completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069185/google-bigquery-in-internal-error-occurred-and-the-request-could-not-be-complet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am an engineer on the BigQuery team. I looked at the job id that you have provided, and it was affected by a temporary internal error this morning that affected a subset of queries for a very short amount of time. It had nothing to do with your query - sorry for the inconvenience it caused you.
edit: typo

Comment: Thanks for the info