# BigQuery Load job : An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed

Tags: google-bigquery

Since 13PM (GMT+1), got lot of error : "An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed."

I didn't make any modification to my system & sometimes it works, sometimes not.

```
Job Type    State      Start Time      Duration      User Email      Bytes Processed   Bytes Billed   Billing Tier   Labels
 ---------- --------- ----------------- ---------- ------------------ ----------------- -------------- -------------- --------
  load       FAILURE   07 Jan 21:05:53   0:00:00    xxx

Error encountered during job execution:
An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.
```

Does someone know if Google is experiencing problems with bigQuery ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: we had yesterday similar (by error message) case. we worked with google support and it was fixed pretty fast. don't have details on this though to share more

Comment: if you post a job-id or two, then maybe one of the Google guys can check it for you. https://status.cloud.google.com/ doesn't show any (official) issues.

Comment: Thanks for the status link. It seems to be solved today, got no more errors in load jobs.

Comment: Very similar issue explained here: stackoverflow.com/a/35070229/133864

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Bigquery: In internal error occurred and the request could not be completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069185/google-bigquery-in-internal-error-occurred-and-the-request-could-not-be-complet)