# Google BigQuery: An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed

Tags: google-bigquery

I receive the following error upon attempting to create a table by manually loading a file from Google Drive.Nothing shows in the Job History so there's no Job ID to share. The file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4saR4nIiLuxbWEzaFhHZmJzXzQ/view?usp=sharing)

Failed to create table: An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.

Comment: Please [file a bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) instead since the StackOverflow community can't help much with this kind of issue.

Comment: Very similar issue explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35070229/133864