# Google BigQuery Internal Error suddenly

Tags: google-bigquery, jobs

I have a BigQuery job that has been executing daily for the past several months 
but now has failed with an internal error.

One example is

`BigQuery` error in query operation:

```
Error processing job 
'xxxxxxxxxx:bqjob_re49da4d82a18dbe_0000016322be54d7_1': An internal error 
occurred and the request could not be completed.
```

Would it be possible to know why this job is causing an internal bigquery error and if there's something I can do to fix it?

Comment: I removed the `processing` tag since the question has nothing to do with the programming language called Processing. Please read the description of a tag before deciding to use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Bigquery: In internal error occurred and the request could not be completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069185/google-bigquery-in-internal-error-occurred-and-the-request-could-not-be-complet)

Answer (score 2):

If this error continues for more than few hours contact with Google support/submit ticket if you have access to GCP support portal.
If not - please use public tracker https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: I appreciate your comment.
Furthermore I investigated this incident, I founded the following information.

https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/cloud-networking/18007
>We are investigating an issue with increased packet loss in us-central1 with Google Cloud Networking.
>Incident began at 2018-05-02 14:02 and ended at 2018-05-02 14:19 (all times are US/Pacific).

The internal error occurred at between 06:19 and 06:24 in 2018-05-02.It was nearly at the same time of day.

Comment: As explained in the [BigQuery documentation for troubleshooting errors](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors#internalError), `internalError` messages may require a deeper investigation and require more information in order to identify the root cause. As suggested in the documentation page I shared and as @AlexeyMaloletkin said, you should contact support or use PIT. In any case, as a general advice, backend/internal errors may be temporary and may be solved by retrying using a [exponential backoff](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/exponential-backoff) strategy.